# Google Maps Javascript V3: remove a route, but keep other routes displayed

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've created the following testcase in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Wtb3/15/. When I check a checkbox for route A or route B, the routes are displayed. So far, so good ...

```
  if (routes.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
          var route = routes[i];
          var request = {
              origin: route.origin,
              destination: route.destination,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
          };

          var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
              suppressMarkers: true,
              preserveViewport: true,
              polylineOptions: {
                  strokeColor: '#C6D300'
              }
          });
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          directionsDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);

          directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

But when I uncheck them, I want to clear the selected route. I keep track of all directionDisplay's using an array (to put the map value to 'null'). First I clear everything, then I redraw every route which is still in the list.

The problem: routes are still in the map, even if I uncheck them ...

Any idea's what exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `length` of array in `for` loop so `setMap(null)` is never called. Code should be changed from

```
  if (directionsDisplays.length > 0) {
      for(var i = 0; i < directionsDisplays; i++) {
          directionsDisplays[i].setMap(null);
      }
  }
```

to

```
  if (directionsDisplays.length > 0) {
      for(var i = 0; i < directionsDisplays.length; i++) {
          directionsDisplays[i].setMap(null);
      }
  }
  ...
```

And additional fix for closure problem:

```
  // Draw all routes
  if (routes.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {

        (function(i){
          var route = routes[i];
          var request = {
              origin: route.origin,
              destination: route.destination,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
          };
          ....

        })(i);

      }
  }
```

Updated [example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Wtb3/19/)

Comment: Correct answer. By the way: why the if clause here?

Comment: That's users code from jsfiddle. I've already seen that usage in some book/articles and it seems that people use it as some performance improvements. In my opinion it is completely unnecessary if there is correct check in for loop.

Comment: Thanks, here's my latest code: http://jsfiddle.net/4Wtb3/18/, but if I check both of the routes, only 1 of them is visible. Any idea?

Comment: Closure problem with routes[i]. I will put change in your fiddle

Comment: Thanks Anton, works like a charm now. Can you explain me the problem with the close problem? ...

Comment: Closure problem (not 100% exact explanation): routes[i] is part of request which is used in directionsService.route() call and that one is asynchronous call. for loop finishes quickly, but those async calls are started later and in original call they do no use proper indexes but just the last one. So we have to provide correct indexes  using that func() wrapper. Closure is actually very useful feature of JS.